# Kubectl get events with two different field selectors doesn't work

Tags: kubernetes, events, containers

kubectl get events with two field selectors on source doesnt give the results as expected. I tried some other options as well

When I try to use the kubectl command to get events for two different field selectors it only returns events for one of them

kubectl get events --field-selector source=deployment-controller --field-selector source=kubelet

```
LAST SEEN   TYPE     REASON    OBJECT                               MESSAGE
10m         Normal   Killing   pod/loadgenerator-5c9656f8d6-2j9nt   Stopping container main
10m         Normal   Killing   pod/loadgenerator-5c9656f8d6-5glbv   Stopping container main
10m         Normal   Killing   pod/loadgenerator-5c9656f8d6-5xqvx   Stopping container main
10m         Normal   Killing   pod/loadgenerator-5c9656f8d6-bdggt   Stopping container main
10m         Normal   Killing   pod/loadgenerator-5c9656f8d6-kwkw5   Stopping container main
10m         Normal   Killing   pod/loadgenerator-5c9656f8d6-m4nbh   Stopping container main
```

kubectl get events --field-selector source=kubelet --field-selector source=deployment-controller

```
LAST SEEN   TYPE     REASON              OBJECT                     MESSAGE
12m         Normal   ScalingReplicaSet   deployment/loadgenerator   Scaled down replica set loadgenerator-5c9656f8d6 to 4
```

How can I get events from both in a single command?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the chained field selector option, **comma** separated

```
kubectl get pods --field-selector=status.phase!=Running,spec.restartPolicy=Always
```

Example

```
kubectl get events --field-selector=source=kubelet,source=deployment-controller
```

Ref : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/field-selectors/#chained-selectors

Comment: This doesn't seem to work

kubectl get events --field-selector=source=kubelet,source=deployment-controller
No resources found in default namespace.
aritra [ ~ ]$ kubectl get events --field-selector=source=deployment-controller
LAST SEEN   TYPE     REASON              OBJECT                     MESSAGE
21s         Normal   ScalingReplicaSet   deployment/loadgenerator   Scaled up replica set loadgenerator-5c9656f8d6 to 8
aritra [ ~ ]$ kubectl get events --field-selector=source=kubelet
<shows some events>

Comment: yes you are right it uses the AND condition, you can use the `jsonpath` also